# Windows-10 batchfiles are based on DATE command, how to use on lower Windows versions

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, command-line, date, regional-settings

I'm working on two (virtual) machines:

- First is a Windows 10 machine
- Second is a Windows 7 machine

On both, the short date formats are equal: `dd.MM.yyyy`
On both, I'm running the same batchfile, based on the `DATE` command.

I'm having differences in the results, related to the outcome of the `DATE` command results:

- On Windows 10 : `The current date is: st 22.03.2017`
- On Windows 7  : `The current date is: 22.03.2017`

As you can see, the difference is due to the presence of the name of today (`st` is an abbreviation of the Czech word for `Wednesday`).

The Windows 10 system is the master, so my question: how can I alter the Windows-7 system to include the first two letters of the name of the day?

As tests, I've already tried the following for a short date format:

```
dd dd.MM.yyyy   // this is better, the length of the format is good,
                   but it does not start with the initials of the day's name.
dddd dd.MM.yyyy // this starts with the day's name, but completely, 
                   and I only want the first two letters.
```

Meanwhile I had a further look at the problem: the date format seems to be used on two places:

1. While working with the `DATE` commandline command (there I need a format like 
   `xx dd.MM.yyyy` (whatever that `xx` might be) for further processing
2. During following `echo`: `for /r %DIRECTORY% %I in ("*.*") do echo %~tfI`
   The idea is to show a timestamp and the filename, something like: 
   `22.03.2016 13:50 <filename>` (without `xx`)

Comment: It's not possible to have 2 character weekdays in Windows 7.

Comment: I see two choices: (1) use long day format, but change the day names to their short equivalents, though this means that you will never see the true long day names; (2) write your own program to report the date: this would be only a few lines of `C`, and will be completely independent of regional settings, or it could be done in a somewhat complex batch file which manipulates the contents of the `%DATE% variable.

Comment: Use `wmic` or PowerShell to manipulate the date in a Locale, Regional, and Language settings independent way. See my answer [Batch script (cmd) resulting in DD-MM-YYYY\_weekday format](//superuser.com/a/1086182) for some tips.

Comment: @AFH: unfortunately even writing an own little program does not solve the issue: I would need to call this program "date.exe", but when I launch `Date`, even in the directory where I've just compiled "date.exe", it still keeps on taking the commandline `DATE` command instead.

Comment: Why do you need to give it the same name? Why not call it `CzDate.exe` or something similar? In `cmd` the `date` command is a shell built-in, so will always be chosen in preference to an external `date.exe`, unless you add a path to the call, eg `.\date`; alternatively, for command-line use (not in a batch file) you can set an alias, eg `doskey date=.\date.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a mess, but I believe I've found a solution for the issue:

The point is the following: On Windows 10, even while having a simple date format (like `dd.MM.yyyy`), the `date /T` commandline adds the first characters of the day, so we get the following:

```
date /T
st 22.03.2017
```

And my collegues have built their batchfiles around the presence of those "st" characters. Running those batchfiles on lower Windows versions gives the mentioned problems.

At the beginning of the batchfiles, I've added the line:

```
DATE=xx %DATE%
```

(very childish, I admit)
This makes the batchfiles work on my Windows-7 computer.
In order to make it work on both systems, I just need to add a check on the platform, something like:

```
set WINDOWS_10=%ver | findstr /C:"Version 10"%
if "WINDOWS_10"=="" (
  set DATE=xx %DATE%)
```

I didn't check it yet on Windows-10 PC, but I believe this will do the trick.

Comment: I can't check Win7 any more, as I upgraded all my W7 systems, but on Win10 your `set Windows_10=` command doesn't work: you need `ver | findstr /C:"Version 10"`, followed by `if errorlevel 1 set DATE=xx %DATE%`. This will affect what `%DATE%` returns, but the `date` command itself will be unaffected. You should also `set DATE=` first, to remove the local variable, and again before exit, so as not to affect other batch files called from the same `cmd` instance.

Comment: It does not add them if you altered your settings.

Comment: @AFH: thanks for the warning, but the batchfiles are to be used from the task scheduler, so there will never be any other programs to be run from the same `cmd` instance.

Answer (score 1):

In windows 7 you must use `ddd` to have a similar format, which is 3 characters, not 2.

So you can use *ddd dd.MM.yyyy*. That's the supported format.

A way to get to 2 chars there would be to remove one with a batch file.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. He want's to add to the Windows 7 machine not remove from the Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Looks like the requirement is the other way around. I have updated.

Comment: Maybe this might be helpful after all: do you have any idea how somebody managed to get it done on Windows 10?
Short date format: `dd.MM.yyyy`
DATE commandline result : `st 22.03.2017`
=> How did they manage getting this result starting with `st `?

Comment: You will have no st if you only modify it to dd.MM.yyyy. To re-add the st, re-set must be in dd dd.MM.yyyy format.